# How can we improve our web development workflow?

Tags: unit-testing, workflow

How can multiple developers work on the same website (CSS, JavaScript, ASP.NET).
We use SVN as source control, but the problem is more in regards of testing and general workflow.
I know we could do unit tests and we have for our API, but I don't see how we can do unit testing for our frontend? 
We get a lot of problems in the frontend like:

1. Developer 1 changes CSS and it messes up CSS for developer 2.
2. Developer 1 changes JavaScript and components developer 2 made stops working.
3. Developer 1 removed an ID or a CSS class in C# (code behind) and CSS styling is lost or JavaScript stops working.

It's basically things of that nature. 
What we do now is manually test everything in all major browsers and we spend too much time on that.

Any good suggestions on how we can improve our way of working? Keep in mind that it's a website and we are struggling with problems related to that.

Comment: "I don't see how we can do unit testing for our frontend?"  Are you asking for a front-end testing tool?  Like selenium?  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: S.Lott Yes, and maybe other suggestions on how we could work to avoid having the problems mentioned or at least reduce them.

Comment: Unit testing is the solution you already named.  It's what everyone else does.  That's why I don't understand your question.  You've already made the most important suggestion.  Test.  If you're not testing, there are no other suggestions that make sense.

Comment: Well I am looking into selenium as you mentioned and I will need to digg in to see what limitations it has. Even though you did not understand my question you managed to give me some useful information:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a management issue rather than a workflow issue.

You need to be proactive at managing the situation and be tough.

You have a source control system in place, what you need to do is:-

1. Enforce day end (or more frequent if preferred) check ins.
2. Rollback work if it doesn't work. You have to be tough on this point to ensure the developers understand that you mean it.
3. You need to actively communicate the above to your team to make sure they understand the new work procedures.

It'd only take a few weeks for it to sink in, after that you can relax the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce releases/iterations/milestones; and publish them only from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not possibly break the site areas up into segments and assign developer responsibilities to each, even if it means sandboxing the "base" code of the site (framework / main CSS / main JavaScript) and assigning a specific responsibility to it? You can then task developers to keep their CSS / JavaScript separate from the main files and merge them before testing and release.

We've had similar problems where I work and this approach seemed to sort it out for the most part. For each segment we built we created a new folder in each of the respective projects (DAL / BL / Presentation), based on the functionalities / modules / segments, each with their own site content (JavaScript / CSS), but still making sure that some generic styling and JavaScript being available to all developers.

An official Agile project management methodology (like Scrum) has huge benefits in an environment like this, as you get to discuss these issues on a daily basis and, if over-arching requirements for new CSS and JavaScript are identified by all developers, it can be integrated into the site's base content.

Comment: We have a complete project with custom controls. We reference this project from our webapplication, but the CSS is actually located in our webapplication and not in the custom controls project. Is that  smart way of moving our CSS to the custom controls project and just reference to it from the webapplication?

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer for this, it all depends what works for your setup and your project. I only stated what we did and that it worked for us - maybe it can work for you, maybe it won't. :) What is a non-negotiable though, is implementing some form of project management and quality assurance in your development. Separating the core content files from the custom modules / controls might be a good way of controlling your source code.